# Could scheduler automatically migrate the thread whose affinity has been set to a very busy cpu through `sched_setaffinity` to a free cpu?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

Could scheduler automatically migrate the thread whose affinity has been set to a very busy cpu through `sched_setaffinity` to a free cpu?

**Does `sched_setaffinity` implement a "hard affinity" or a "soft affinity"?**

What i called "soft affinity" is that it tells scheduler the thread prefers to run on a particular cpu and could be migrated to other cpu if necessary.

What i called "hard affinity" is that it tells scheduler the thread must run on particular cpu no matter how long the thread has to wait for the cpu resources.

**I clearly remember that there are apis which could provide "soft affinity" and "hard affinity" under windows indeed.Is there any api could provide "soft affinity" under linux?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If a process has affinity to one CPU only, it will only run on that CPU no matter what. In other words, this fits your definition of "hard affinity".

This feature can of course be a double edged sword if used incorrectly: setting the affinity of a task to a single CPU gives great benefit if the CPU is dedicated to that task only, but degrades performance if the CPU is not and it somehow gets under heavy load.

Comment: I remember that there are apis which could provide "soft affinity" and "hard affinity" **under windows** indeed.Is there any api could provide "soft affinity" under linux?

Comment: Not really. You can set the affinity to more than one CPU and the scheduler will move the process to the less busy one when possible.

Comment: I don't mean that.I really remember windows provide "soft affinity" api.I would found out it.

Comment: @sunshilong369 well... ok. You are asking about Linux though, and this is the answer to your question. If you want you can ask the same question for Windows and I'm sure someone else will give you another answer.